# Issues with ListView in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Please see the issues in attached images and let me know how to fix them if you know.

-if I have large number of items, everything looks fine
-If around 6 items then I get empty space on top and bottom of the scroll bar
-if 3 or less items, then I get unwanted spacing between the items

Please see the code for the list:

```
<!--list to hold thumbnails for each slide-->
            <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="White"  Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="10" Grid.RowSpan="27">

                <ListView  Name="Thumbnails" HorizontalContentAlignment ="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Padding="0"  Background ="#81AFD3" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="10" Grid.RowSpan="27" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" SelectionChanged="Thumbnails_SelectionChanged"  >

                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>


                    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <UniformGrid Columns="1"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemsPanel>

                    <ListView.Resources>

                        <!--RESOURCES FOR SCROLLBAR-->

                        <!--Control colors.-->
                        <Color x:Key="WindowColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
                        <Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorLight">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
                        <Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorDark">#FF7381F9</Color>

                        <Color x:Key="DisabledControlLightColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
                        <Color x:Key="DisabledControlDarkColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
                        <Color x:Key="DisabledForegroundColor">#FF888888</Color>

                        <Color x:Key="SelectedBackgroundColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
                        <Color x:Key="SelectedUnfocusedColor">#FFDDDDDD</Color>

                        <Color x:Key="ControlLightColor">White</Color>
                        <Color x:Key="ControlMediumColor">#FF7381F9</Color>
                        <Color x:Key="ControlDarkColor">#FF211AA9</Color>

                        <Color x:Key="ControlMouseOverColor">#FF3843C4</Color>
                        <Color x:Key="ControlPressedColor">#FF211AA9</Color>


                        <Color x:Key="GlyphColor">#FF444444</Color>
                        <Color x:Key="GlyphMouseOver">sc#1, 0.004391443, 0.002428215, 0.242281124</Color>

                        <!--Border colors-->
                        <Color x:Key="BorderLightColor">#FFCCCCCC</Color>
                        <Color x:Key="BorderMediumColor">#FF888888</Color>
                        <Color x:Key="BorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>

                        <Color x:Key="PressedBorderLightColor">#FF888888</Color>
                        <Color x:Key="PressedBorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>

                        <Color x:Key="DisabledBorderLightColor">#FFAAAAAA</Color>
                        <Color x:Key="DisabledBorderDarkColor">#FF888888</Color>

                        <Color x:Key="DefaultBorderBrushDarkColor">Black</Color>

                        <!--Control-specific resources.-->
                        <Color x:Key="HeaderTopColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
                        <Color x:Key="DatagridCurrentCellBorderColor">Black</Color>
                        <Color x:Key="SliderTrackDarkColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>

                        <Color x:Key="NavButtonFrameColor">#FF3843C4</Color>

                        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MenuPopupBrush"
                     EndPoint="0.5,1"
                     StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
                Offset="0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}"
                Offset="0.5" />
                            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
                Offset="1" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>

                        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndicatorAnimatedFill"
                     StartPoint="0,0"
                     EndPoint="1,0">
                            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                <GradientStopCollection>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#000000FF"
                    Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#600000FF"
                    Offset="0.4" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#600000FF"
                    Offset="0.6" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#000000FF"
                    Offset="1" />
                                </GradientStopCollection>
                            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>

                        <!--RESOURCES FOR SCROLLBAR END-->

                        <Style x:Key="ScrollBarLineButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
                            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
                            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false" />
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                                        <!--HERE WE ADJUST PROPERTIES ON TOP AND BOTTOM BUTTONS -->
                                        <Border x:Name="Border"  CornerRadius="4,4,4,4" BorderThickness="0" >
                                            <Border.BorderBrush>
                                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                                    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                        <GradientStopCollection>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderMediumColor}" Offset="0.0" />
                                                            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderDarkColor}" Offset="1.0" />
                                                        </GradientStopCollection>
                                                    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                                            </Border.BorderBrush>
                                            <Border.Background>
                                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                                    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                        <GradientStopCollection>
                                                            <!--HERE WE SET THE KEYS COLOR-->
                                                            <GradientStop Color="White"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" />
                                                        </GradientStopCollection>
                                                    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                                            </Border.Background>
                                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ControlPressedColor}" />
                                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#79B0D4" />
                                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <Path x:Name="Arrow" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="{Binding Content,  RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" >
                                                <Path.Fill>
                                                    <!--HERE WE SET THE ARROW COLOR-->
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#79B0D4"/>
                                                </Path.Fill>
                                            </Path>
                                        </Border>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>

                        <Style x:Key="ScrollBarPageButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
                            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
                            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
                            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false" />
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                                        <!--HERE WE SET Background buttons PROPERTIES-->
                                        <Border Background="Black" Height="0"/>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>



                        <Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumb" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
                            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
                            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
                            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false" />
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                                        <!--HERE WE SET THE THUMB COLOR CORNER AND BORDER-->
                                        <Border CornerRadius="1" Background="#D8E8F5" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0" Width="16" Height="250" />
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>

                        <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalScrollBar" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition MaxHeight="18" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*" />
                                    <RowDefinition MaxHeight="18" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <!--HERE WE SET THE ENTIRE SCROLLBAR BACKROUND AND CORNERS-->
                                <Border Grid.RowSpan="3" CornerRadius="5" Background="#A9CCE5"  />
                                <RepeatButton Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}" Height="18" Command="ScrollBar.LineUpCommand" Content="M 0 4 L 8 4 L 4 0 Z" />
                                <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="1" IsDirectionReversed="true">
                                    <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                        <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand" />
                                    </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <Track.Thumb>
                                        <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}" Margin="1,0,1,0">
                                            <Thumb.BorderBrush>

                                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                                                    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                        <GradientStopCollection>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderLightColor}" Offset="0.0" />
                                                            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderDarkColor}" Offset="1.0" />
                                                        </GradientStopCollection>
                                                    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                </LinearGradientBrush>

                                            </Thumb.BorderBrush>
                                            <Thumb.Background>

                                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                                                    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                        <GradientStopCollection>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" Offset="0.0" />
                                                            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}" Offset="1.0" />
                                                        </GradientStopCollection>
                                                    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                </LinearGradientBrush>

                                            </Thumb.Background>
                                        </Thumb>
                                    </Track.Thumb>
                                    <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                        <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand" />
                                    </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                </Track>
                                <RepeatButton Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}" Height="18" Command="ScrollBar.LineDownCommand" Content="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>

                        <ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalScrollBar" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="18" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.00001*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="18" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="3" CornerRadius="2" Background="#F0F0F0" />
                                <RepeatButton Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}" Width="18" Command="ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand" Content="M 4 0 L 4 8 L 0 4 Z" />
                                <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Column="1" IsDirectionReversed="False">
                                    <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                        <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" Command="ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand" />
                                    </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <Track.Thumb>
                                        <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}" Margin="0,1,0,1">

                                            <Thumb.BorderBrush>

                                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                                                    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                        <GradientStopCollection>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderLightColor}" Offset="0.0" />
                                                            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderDarkColor}" Offset="1.0" />
                                                        </GradientStopCollection>
                                                    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                </LinearGradientBrush>

                                            </Thumb.BorderBrush>
                                            <Thumb.Background>

                                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                                    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                        <GradientStopCollection>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" Offset="0.0" />
                                                            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}" Offset="1.0" />
                                                        </GradientStopCollection>
                                                    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                </LinearGradientBrush>

                                            </Thumb.Background>
                                        </Thumb>
                                    </Track.Thumb>
                                    <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                        <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" Command="ScrollBar.PageRightCommand" />
                                    </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                </Track>
                                <RepeatButton Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}" Width="18" Command="ScrollBar.LineRightCommand" Content="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 0 8 Z" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>

                        <Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
                            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
                            <!--<Setter Property="Value" Value="20" />-->
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="18" />
                                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollBar}" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                                    <Setter Property="Width"  Value="18" />
                                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
                                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBar}" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>


                    </ListView.Resources>


                </ListView>

            </Border>
```

[image: OK if large number of items]

[image: If around 6 items then I get empty space on top and bottom of the scroll bar]

[image: if 3 or less items, then I get unwanted spacing between the items]

Comment: The immages are of a very low quality. Furtheremore your question is far to broad. Just pick one problem and put it in here with the information needed to understand the problem, your apptroach to fix it and a description what happens not as expected. Finally read this please before posting such questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <UniformGrid Columns="1"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

This here is the root of your problems. The `UniformGrid` is using the whole available space and creating equally tall cells to fill it.

Either use a `StackPanel` as your Items Panel, or set `VerticalAlignment="Top"` to the `UniformGrid`.

Comment: Thank you so much. That indeed fixed the problem with spacing between the items. I just commented out that block. However, the spacing on top and the bottom of the scroll bar still remains.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "spacing on top and the bottom of the scroll bar". I don't see anything wrong with the scroll bar in your images.

Comment: Oh, in second image...you see how it doesn't go all the way up...i didn't leave it in that position randomly. that's the maximum it can reach when I have around 6 items...and same thing applies at the bottom

Comment: I fixed it by taking out the 'Height' property for the Thumb so I guess now it resizes dynamically instead of being fixed to 250